# If $a_{2n}-a_n\to 0$, does the sequence $a_n$ have a limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Is this claim true or false?

> Given $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\ (a_{2n}-a_n)=0$ then $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\ a_n$ exists.

Comment: This one is worth thinking about for a long time on your own before seeking hints.

Comment: False. Take $a_n=\log\log n$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's false: take $a_n = 1$ if $n = 2^m$ for some $m$, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Very nice!$\ \ $